# Simple Percentage Column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to SQL and looking to pick up a few simple tricks. I have managed to create a query that selects each different type of car permit (*chargeType*), counts the number issued for each one (*num*), and adds a column that shows the total number of permits issued (*total*). The code is below.

```
SELECT chargeType, 
       COUNT(chargeType) AS num,
       (SELECT COUNT(chargeType) 
       FROM permit) AS total
FROM permit
GROUP BY chargeType
```

I now want to add a final column which shows the percentage of each permit type issued. So the number of each permit type divided by the total multiplied by 100, but I am struggling to do it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Just call it `percentage` and store a numeric INT value - MYSQL uses `%` as it's wildcard selector, so don't store `%` in the db - store just the int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT chargeType,
       num,
       total,
       num / NULLIF(total, 0) * 100 AS Percenatge
FROM   (SELECT chargeType,
               Count(chargeType) AS num,
               (SELECT Count(chargeType)
                FROM   permit)   AS total
        FROM   permit
        GROUP  BY chargeType) a
```

`NULLIF` is used to avoid divide by zero expection

Answer (score 0):

This will work. The plus of this solution is there is no subquery in `SELECT`

```
SELECT *, (num * 100 / total) as percentage
FROM 
(
SELECT
 chargeType, 
 COUNT(chargeType) AS num,
 total,
 (num * 100 / total) as percentage
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(chargeType) as total FROM permit) ttotal
CROSS JOIN
  permit
GROUP BY
 chargeType
) tsub
```